# $viewContentLoaded firing before view content is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here's the shizzle: I have a basic one page angular app where I'm building my portfolio. In controllers I have 3 controllers, and projects is the one I'm having trouble with.

I'm using ng-repeat to get out each project in a list. I'm then targeting them by javascript to resize them correctly.

The thing is that it simply doesn't resize them. They're not loaded before JW.core runs, even if I'm going with $viewContentLoaded as suggested. Hence they are 0px x 0px instead of for example 500 x 500.

I know this since if I set a timeout on the  resize function call within JW.core, it's fine. Then each project has been repeated and can be resized accordingly.

I also figured that since I'm pretty new to angular, I'm probably doing something wrong.

controllers.js:

```
function mainCtrl($scope) {
}

function projectsCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('data/projects/projects.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.projects = data;
  });

  $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
      new JW.core();
  });
}

function aboutCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('data/about/about.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.about = data;
  });
}
```

core.js:

```
var JW = JW || {};

JW.core = function() {

    var initialise = function () {
            new JW.elementDimensions();
        };

    initialise();

};
```

elementdimensions.js:

```
var JW = JW || {};

JW.elementDimensions = function () {

    var scrollbarWidth,
        resizeDim = function (e, ww, wh) {

            var wh = window.innerHeight;    

            $(e).width(ww + 'px');
            $(e).height(wh + 'px');

        },

        initialise = function () {

            var ww = window.innerWidth - scrollbarWidth,
                $targets = $('#projects').find('.project');

            $('.project-wrapper').width((window.innerWidth - scrollbarWidth) * $targets.length);
            $('.project-wrapper').height(window.innerHeight);

            _.each($targets, function(e) {
                resizeDim(e, ww);
                console.log(e);
            })

        };


    initialise();

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        initialise();
    });

    return this;

};
```

and the view:

```
    <div class="project" ng-repeat="project in projects">

        <div class="project-img" style="background: url('{{project.imageUrl}}') fixed;" id="{{project.id}}">
            <div class="info-container">
                <h1>{{project.title}}</h1>
                <p class="description">
                    {{project.description}}
                </p>
                <div class="tags">
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="tag in project.tags">{{tag}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <a class="goto" href="{{project.link}}">{{project.linktext}} →</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: have you tried using a directive instead?

Comment: @charlietfl How do I do that? As I said, very new to angular :(

Answer (score 2):

What you're going to want to do is use **resolve** on your route.

```
$routeProvider.when('/products', {
    templateUrl: 'products.html',
    controler: 'productsCtrl',
    resolve: {
        products: ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('data/projects/projects.json').success(function(data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }]
    }
});
```

Then, in your controller, inject $scope and products instead of $scope and $http, unless you also need $http for anything else once the controller is running, in which case just add products. What this will do essentially is delay the initialization of the controller until the content is loaded.

Comment: Big thanks for the quick response. Your instructions are very clear, and I'm absolutely sure that I understand it, yet it doesn't work. It initiates the controller, but never fires the viewcontentloaded event, and none of my angular templating works it magic. It's as if it doesn't find the json-data, actually.

Comment: In your controller, set $scope.products = products. You might not need to wait for viewcontentloaded if you set that before calling new JW.core(); Sorry if that doesn't help. I'm not sure if viewcontentloaded is the right thing to use in this situation, but I could be wrong. I'm not familiar with using it.

Comment: I've tried both with and without, the problem still stands. Thanks for the help, but my hunt for a solution continues.

Comment: `$http` already returns a promise no need to use `$q` ... `return $http.get('get/whatever').then(function(response){ return response; });`